# Should I still see my edit once it's rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Let's say I suggested an edit and it was approved by two, rejected by two and finally rejected by a fifth reviewer.

Given that it was a close call and a contentious one, should **I** still get to view the question according to my edit as I deemed it most appropriate the way I edited it?

Does the answer depend on a case by case call?

Comment: No, if it's rejected it doesn't matter how close the vote was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be silly,

Different users would see different versions of the question, which would result in different answers being good / bad.

SO isn't meant to serve individuals, but to provide good questions / answers for *all* future visitors.